# My magento theme is still loading the pages from the previous theme

Tags: php, mysql, css, xml, magento

I recently updated my dev magento site with a new theme, configured it and selected it as the theme in the admin panel. However when i go to the front end it is still using all of the old pages for the main content but the header and footer are the new theme.

[Image of theme selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFEQl.jpg)

Comment: Have you setup the home page from theme under admin > system > web > default pages section. Also try to clear cache from vav/cache folder.

Comment: You should not add your website address with question. Stackover flow is a site where you can ask about your programming related question, Be ready for negative marking

Comment: @mjdevloper It seems like a programming related question as he is having trouble with his website. That's not the reason this question needs editing.

Comment: @walksaus Welcome to SO. In the future, we expect you to paste your code into your question to see what you have done. If you know the specific area of code that is giving you trouble, please post that here. If you could, take screenshots of what you are having trouble with and what you want it to look like.

Comment: Ok  thanks for your help. I removed the web address and wont do that in the future, i thought it may be relevant. I got the home page working. I had all caches turned off but after deleting the contents of var/cache it worked. Still having the issue with every other page (catalog, product, etc.) loading from the previous themes templates.

Answer (score -1):

please have a look at your theme folder path. If it is app/design/frontend/intenso/default/

Then you have to use **Current Package Name** Under **Package** as **intensio(your-theme-name)** & Under **Themes** use **Default** as **default**

For more detail, check screenshot:

[Screenshot explainig solution for showing old theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4a9V.jpg)

Hope it helps

Comment: I already had it selected. I attached a screenshot of my settings already.

Comment: Please check screenshot i attached & fill fields according to that. In your screenshot, you have added intensio to all fields. But we need to fill intensio to Package & fill default in Default under Themes